# How to upload image to twitpic in bada

Tags: social-networking, bada

How to share images in twitpic. Social API in bada is not supporting twitpic. Is there another way for this? and what is meant by multipart form data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By referring sample codes available in SDK we can upload image to server. The example code HTTPUpload with multipartFormdata helped to post the image to twitpic server.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write the protocol implementation yourself. I don't know it myself so I can't give you an exact answer but the bottom line is you should look at the sockets and web http namespaces, read the twitpic protocol for uploading and implement it... the hard way.

On the multipart side, look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages

Comment: Thanks George for that wikipedia link.